# How to split up Python chain?

Tags: python, method-chaining

Does someone use the python-chain package and know if it is possible to split up chains? I would Imagine something like

```
intermediate_result = chain.state() >> step_1 >> step_2

final_result_1 = intermediate_result >> step_3_1 >> step_4_1
final_result_2 = intermediate_result >> step_3_2 >> step_4_2
```

Here the link to the package I mean: https://pypi.org/project/python-chain/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the anwser:

```
intermediate_result = chain.state() >> step_1 >> step_2

final_result_1 = intermediate_result.current >> step_3_1 >> step_4_1
final_result_2 = intermediate_result.current >> step_3_2 >> step_4_2
```

Be aware that this only work if intermediate_result does not contain any non-serializable object such as pyspark dataframes